# Zend_Lucene: How to combine multiple terms?

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, zend-search-lucene

I am searching in an index using two different approaches, one is working, one is not (but should be from reading the documentation). I am wondering what my mistake is.

Here is my first approach which works fine:

```
$query = '+language:EN +country:US';
$hits = $index->find($query);
```

I tried to do the same using `Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term`:

```
$query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm();
$query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term('EN', 'language'), true);
$query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term('US', 'country'), true);
$hits  = $index->find($query);
```

This won't create a result. Removing the `true` option converts the search into an OR search (country=US OR language=EN).

I based the creation of the second approach on the documentation found at http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.search.lucene.query-api.html

Comment: Have you checked if it is because of the case sensitivity?

Comment: Yes, I have just double checked it. It is the same on all fronts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by not using any UPPERCASE characters in the search.

Searching for lowercase characters, even if the data fields are uppercase, solved it.

Example code that worked:

```
$query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm();
$query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term('en', 'language'), true);
$query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term('us', 'country'), true);
$hits  = $index->find($query);
```

The data fields have the values "EN" and "US" and have been indexed as such and the document output confirms this but the search requires a lower case input for some reason.